# Why does the Firefox browser open when I use instaPy but nothing happens next?

Tags: python, instapy, firefox-driver

```
from instapy import InstaPy
insta_username = 'pedram_musavi333'
insta_password = '0000'
session = InstaPy(username=insta_username,password=insta_password,headless_browser=True)
session.login()
```

After executing this code, the Firefox browser opens but nothing happens, then after a while the browser closes and I get several errors
Where exactly is the problem? I

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: I will not receive an error while the browser is open. After a while, the browser will close and I will receive the following errors:
InstaPy Version: 0.6.16
 ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._.  ._. 
Workspace in use: "C:/Users/672170/InstaPy"
1452kb [00:02, 503.71kb/s]

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/instapy-quickstart-master/quickstart.py", line 12, in <module>
    headless_browser=True)
  File "C:\selenium\1\venv\lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 343, in __init__
    geckodriver_log_level,
  File "C:\selenium\1\venv\lib\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 127, in

Comment: set_selenium_local_session
    options=firefox_options,
  File "C:\selenium\1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "C:\selenium\1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\selenium\1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",

Comment: line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\selenium\1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\selenium\1\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 0

Comment: Please don't use comments to clarify; [edit] your question instead, so that you can post it formatted and hence readable.